# Android getCurrentTab(); dont work with dynamic tabs

Tags: android, tabs, onchange

Im pretty new to android and Ive been trying to get the id of the current tab. Thing is, those tabs are created dynamically, as well as their content. When I try to use this code, it says **cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class**.

I tried to convert current_tab_id to string, with parseInt but it crashed the app.

```
Tabs.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                current_tab_id = tabId; << get tag as string works fine
                Tabs.getCurrentTab(); //< the error occurs
                }
            });
```

Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: what are you doing with `Tabs.getCurrentTab();`? referring to any variable?. Then `int x = Tabs.getCurrentTab();`

Comment: Oh, eye error - sorry :) But the fact is i did assign it to a variable, just didnt copy it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the reason that you are getting this error message is that you are declaring your TabHost variable outside of the scope of your "new OnTabChangedListener()". In this case, Java will compile with an out-of-scope reference, but only if the variable is declared final so that the variable is guaranteed to exist in memory.

Try, instead, implementing OnTabChangeListener and then declaring a global class variable, instead of declaring it within your onCreate method.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTabChangeListener {

    TabHost myTabHost;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ...

            myTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {
        myTabHost.getCurrentTab();
    }

}
```